# XmlDocument.Validate ignore properties without [XmlIgnore]

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, schema, xmldocument

I have a object that has a number of properties that aren't present in the xsd file. When doing XmlDocument.Validate is there a way I can tell it to ignore properties that are not present in the xsd and instead just ensure that the properties required by xsd are present in the xml document?

I can get around this by adding [XmlIgnore] attributes all over my class but I would rather accomplish this by convention rather then explicitly add attributes all throughout my object model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there is. Personally I would create a separate DTO, as it sounds like you're trying to make one object serve two jobs. Another option would be to use the `XmlSerializer` ctor that allows you to specify attribs at runtime, but this is much more work than `[XmlIgnore]`.

So if you just want it to work: `[XmlIgnore]`. If you want it to be "pure", create a second DTO model and translate between them.

Comment: creating a second model would work, but this is in my actual domain model and is for persistence to an in-house orm so it's a little overkill to create a whole duplicate model. blerg. thanks anyways

Comment: I guessed as much - and that is fine as long as the mapping is 1:1, but when you start to drift between the two, it is often easier to cut your losses and split the types / responsibility. Otherwise you're going to be fighting it regularly.